# Whats the error with this c++ construct?

Tags: c++

I am a newbee in C++. Tried the following code:

```
while((char c = cin.get()) != 'q')
{  //do anything
}
```

when I try to compile, it fails with following

> error: expected primary-expression before "char".

Please help me understand this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a declaration as a part of an expression.

```
while ((char c = cin.get()) != 'q') { ...
//      |----------------| <---------------------- this is a declaration
//     |-------------------------| <-------------- this is an expression
```

You *can* have a declaration directly inside the parentheses of the loop (not in any nested parentheses):

```
while (char c = cin.get()) { ...
```

but this stops on `!c`, which is not what you want.

This will work:

```
while (int c = cin.get() - 'q') { // ugly code for illustrative purpose
 c += 'q';
 ...
}
```

and so will this:

```
for (char c; (c = cin.get()) != 'q'; ) { // ugly code for illustrative purpose
  ...
}
```

Update: see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190748/775806).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char c;
while((c = cin.get()) != 'q')
{  //do anything
}
```

You are declaring the variable inside parantheses, hence the error:

```
while (char c = cin.get() != 'q')
```

Comment: You may like to try `while(char c = cin.get() != 'q')`

Comment: @bubble, there are statements and there are expressions. Statements cannot be used as part of expressions. `char c = ...` is a statement.

Comment: yours with "double" bracekts wont work because it does not need the local c variable any more and discards it already only memorizing "true" for the while and this turns ugly for the true != 'q' comparism ;-)

Comment: @ Don Reba they can... if you use a 'if( a = 1 )' (notice the missing second =) it will always do the stuff inside the if and also setting a to 1

Comment: @Najzero I feel `(true != 'q')` is still a valid comparison. It should always return `true`. Isn't it ?

Comment: hm yep true, my first guess was it casts 'q' to a boolean before comparism... it does not. So hmmm